# Minimum SDK version when using Google Awareness API?

Tags: android, api, android-version, google-awareness

Just knew about Google's new Context aware popularly known as Google Awareness API , What should be the minimum version when using Google Awareness API?

Are there any restrictions or precautions should be taken when using it?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find some best practices and suggestions from Google:
https://developers.google.com/awareness/best-practices

If you need only the Awareness API, import only that:

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-contextmanager:9.4.0'`

The full play-services import is not necessary, it is too heavy.

The sample app from Google uses minSDK 14.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-awareness

You can easily try it out, if it works on lower API level too.

I think the "only" restriction is the "play-services".
So if your target devices have no play-services (e.g. lot of Chinese products), your app will not work.

Comment: Nice answer but I want to know exact version @danesaz